# Why Does My Font Size Looks Too Large in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, typography, font-size

In InDesign, I have my font size set to 6 pts, but it definitely looks larger than that. What settings can I look at to try to change this occurrence?

Comment: What do you mean by "looks larger"? Zoomed in? On screen? Printed? In relation to another typeface? Some screenshots may help

Comment: With a decent font that follows some basic typography rules, etc, 6pt is always 6pt, so not sure what it is you are asking here? :)

Comment: For which law firm are you composing 6pt  text? If you want it to look smaller (yipes!), try Caslon.

Comment: @Stan done and done. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

A typeface with a large x-height (the relative size of lowercase vs. uppercase letters) may have one typeface 'look' bigger than the other.

Moreover, and no less common, point size is hardly a measure for actual glyph size. Verdana uppercase is larger than Garamond uppercase, for example. Some typefaces have ridiculously small letters for their point sizes.

This image illustrates both effects:
[image: x-height and height difference]

The best you can do is eyeball it and adjust the point size. Print a proof of your work on a desktop printer and try and see what point size works best.

As was said in the comments, 6pt is awfully small—on the border of legibility. Unless you are indeed lay-outing legalese or something similar, consider a larger point size!

Comment: +1  ...x-height isn't the relative size of lower vs upper case though, it's simply the height of the lower case letters